# SQL Plus closing after script is run

Tags: sqlplus

New to programming and SQL.

When I run a script within a SQL Plus command box window, the command window closes.
How can I stop the script from closing the window automatically please?

First, I am logging into the DB host, then I run the script and I cannot tell what the output is, if it has errored, etc?

For example:

1. Within Windows, run sqlplus
2. login using 'schema/schemapassword@hostname
3. run script using @c:\thisisanexampleofthescript.sql

At this point, the sql plus window closes

Thanks
Brian

Comment: start shell (`cmd`, `bash`, etc) and inside start `sqlplus`

Comment: I should have been more explicit:

1. Within Windows, run sqlplus
2. login using 'schema/schemapassword@hostname
3. run script using @c:\thisisanexampleofthescript.sql

At this point, the sql plus window closes

Comment: Run first a `cmd` and inside run `sqlplus`. `sqlplus` just close the window when it finish.

Comment: @RomeoNinov - THANK YOU! That worked like a charm, sorry for the delay in responding back!

Comment: I add it as answer, feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

To keep the window with `sqlplus` open first run `cmd` and then inside run `sqlplus`. Because `sqlplus` just close the window when it finish.